# Is a certain fonction $C^1$?

Tags: real-analysis

A small open question.

Let $f \in C(\Bbb{R}^n,\Bbb{R}^n)$ be a continuous function. Is the function : $g : \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
g(x) = \int_0^1 \langle f(tx),x \rangle dt =  \bigg\langle \int_0^1f(tx) dt ,x \bigg\rangle
$$ a differentiable function?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is a fonction? Also, why would you ask an open question on here? If it's open, the answer isn't known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. Example: set $f(x) = 2||x||_1e_1$, where $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ is the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Then for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$,
$$g(x) = \int_0^1 2t||x||_1 \langle e_1,x \rangle dt = ||x||_1x_1.$$
The function $g$ is not differentiable at points $x$ such that $x_1 \ne 0$ and such that another coordinate of $x$ vanishes.